# Connection refused when attempting to connect the docker URL

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline

I have confirmed that alpine/socat is running on http://127.0.0.1:2376/
Potentially an issue with daemon not being connected, help would be greatly appreciated. TIA
Using OSX

Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:2376
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
Caused: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:2376
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:777)
at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:327)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:340)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:636)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:583)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:500)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:462)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:897)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

Comment: Can you edit the question to include a [mcve]?  Remember that anyone who can access the Docker socket has almost unlimited capabilities on the host (on OSX, merely unlimited access to the user's home directory) and you almost never want to make it available over a network socket.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like jenkins doesn't have permissions to use docker,
try

```
sudo usermod -aG docker jenkins
```